# Need PHP help assigning a piece of data from an Amazon S3 query to a variable

Tags: php, arrays, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using the AWS PHP SDK along with the code listed below to return a list of objects associated with a folder on my Amazon S3 service:

```
$s3 = new AmazonS3();

$response = $s3->list_objects($bucket, array(
    'prefix' => 'myfolder/'
));

print_r($response->body);
```

I don't want to use "print_r" part.

The $response seems to be an array with a bunch of stuff in it:
Key, LastModified, ETag, Size, Owner

What would the PHP code look like that would loop through $response and assign one of the bits to a variable. For example, one piece of data in $response is "Key" that looks something like this:

```
[Key] => myfolder/myfile.pdf
```

what I need is:

```
myfolder/myfile.pdf
```

Please provide the code I would need to loop through the data within $response and assign each instance of "KEY" to a variable called: $haasfilepath.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It has been awhile since I've used php, but this should be work if I understand your problem. 
If $response is an array with each element containing an associative array for the matching object.

```
$hassfilepath = Array();
    foreach($response as $element){
        $haasfilepath << $element[key];
    }
```

The foreach will allow you to loop through all the objects returned in response. Within the loop you then push each [Key] into the array that is $haasfilepath. You now have a variable with an array of all key's returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($response->body as $key => $haasfilepath)
{
 echo 'value for key ', $key, ' is ', $haasfilepath, '<br>';
}
```

or, if you only need the key "key":

```
$haasfilepath = $response->body['key'];
echo $haasfilepath;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the response will be an XML file (not an array-name-value-pair) and you have to parse the XML file. Try researching xpath and similar methods in parse XMl file in php.